# Need some clarification regarding the MVC pattern

Tags: model-view-controller

I know MVC quite well (at least i think i do) and I've developed quite a lot of application using this approach. One thing bugs me though:

In every diagram i saw of the model it was drawn as a triangle with a direct connection between the controller and the view/model, but also a connection between the view and model (i.e. the model and view speak directly without the controller in the middle).

In all my years as a developer there was always a complete seperation between the model and view, with the controller acting as the middleman, and as i understand, this is also the best practice.

So under what situation would i want the model to talk directly to the view? can you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model doesn't talk to the view. But the view displays data contained in the model, and calls methods from the model to display them. That's probably why there is a link between them in your diagram:

1. controller gets model from database (via the service layer) and stores it in the request
2. controller dispatches to the appropriate view
3. view gets data from the model and generates HTML

Comment: Thats what i thought, but i saw some articles stating that the view might ask the model for updates directly like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288928/Differences-between-MVC-and-MVP-for-Beginners , so is this wrong/old approach?

Comment: This article talks about the MVC pattern on desktop applications, not in the context of web development.

Answer (score 1):

Some Model-View-Presenter design patterns with "Supervising Controllers" allow the View to be updated directly from the Model, for simple data binding tasks:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647543.aspx

There is also the ModelView - ViewModel pattern, but it's sort of the same thing as MVC, just with the Controller logic moved to the View.  Some WPF apps use MV-VM for speedy UI updates from the data source:

http://russelleast.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/overview-of-the-modelview-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-and-data-binding/

But both alternatives (MVP w/ Supervising C, and MV-VM) are really just variations of MVC under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, i know of these patterns and it does not exactly answer my question, but you get an upvote for the efort :)

Comment: Thanks.  An example might be in a web page where SQL and database connection code would be written on the web page itself to update selections as users made them eg. a user selects a country from a drop-down list, then the webpage passed the drop-down value into the SQL to call the database again to get the cities for that country in another drop-down list.